# Cosa significa "tramatura"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Nel museo di Reims*, di Daniele Del Giudice, ho letto:

> È come con la musica, anche per quella ci dev'essere un deposito nella mente, e quando è cosí buio se mi sforzo riesco a risentire brani interi, è una macchina difficile da mettere in moto all'inizio ma dopo non c'è modi da fermarla, comincia con il solo tema, una alla volta si aggiungono le **tramature** e gli accenti, entrano le armonie, la musica si gonfia, passa dalla testa alle orecchie, ma non per via interna, passa da fuori, come se davvero io la ascoltassi.

Non so cosa sono "le tramature" in questo brano. Ho cercato il vocabolo "tramatura", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: In questo senso è forse più usuale [“tessitura”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tessitura/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il termine **tramatura** deriva da [trama](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trama/), che insieme all'ordito costituiscono lo scheletro di un tessuto. Nel passaggio da te indicato il termine viene usato in modo figurato per indicare lo schema, la struttura che il brano musicale segue.

Per esempio il termine tramatura viene largamente usato nell'industria dei tessuti di carbonio:

> Tessuto di carbonio 90g/m², larghezza 1m. Per ali stampati, fusoliere
>   ultraleggeri e rigidi. Filamento molto sottile (1K) e **tramatura** tela.